# Why install ‘black’ rather than ‘python3-black’?

Tags: apt, python

I am using Kubuntu with sway as a window manager, but I don’t
think that makes a difference to my problem.

I just spent a long time trying to enter `sudo apt install python3-black`. The answer, it turns out after a Google search,
is that the package is labelled `black`, not `python3-black`.

In retrospect, I suppose I could have used `apt search` but
was feeling a bit frustrated at the time.

Just for future reference, is there a general rule for when
python packages are labelled `python3-*` and when they are
not?

Many thanks

Comment: I would expect `python3-*` packages to be primarily libraries, which may incidentally provide commands as well. In black's case, the command is the main thing, I don't even know if it provides a general library.

Comment: Thanks for coming back. This actually came about after first looking for flake8 -- which is python3-flake8.

Comment: No, the actual `flake8` binary is in [the `flake8` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/flake8/filelist)

Comment: Ooh: so it seems, doing a ```apt show```. On the other hand, my apt log shows ```sudo apt install python3-flake8``` as a successful command (dated 2023-08-04). (PS sorry for delay in noticing your comment!)